# Check in-memory version of an object against the data in the database

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, hibernate-session

I have a Hibernate project where a call to `update()` needs to compare the modified object in memory to the data that has already been saved to the database. For example, my business logic states that if a record is "effective" (the effective date is today or earlier), an update cannot change the effective date. In order to accomplish this, I have the following code (it's a little long and involved):

**Manager**

```
public class LogicManager {

  @Autowired
  SessionFactory sessionFactory

  private Session getSession() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
  }

  public MemberRecord findRecord(Integer id) {
    // << Code to check authorization >>
    return memberRecordDAO.findById(id);
  }

  public void updateRecord(MemberRecord record) {
    getSession().evict(record);
    MemberRecord oldRecord = memberRecordDAO.findById(record.getId());

    Date oldEffectiveDate = oldRecord.getEffectiveDate();
    if ( isEffective(oldEffectiveDate) && 
         !oldEffectiveDate.equals(record.getEffectiveDate)) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot change date");
    }

    // << Other data checks >>
    memberRecordDAO.update(record);
  }
}
```

**DAO**

```
public class MemberRecordDAO {
  @Autowired
  private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  private Session getSession() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
  }

  public MemberRecord findById(Integer id) {
    return (MemberRecord)getSession()
             .getNamedQuery("findMemberById")
             .setInteger("id", id)
             .uniqueResult();
  }
}
```

**Client Code**

```
// ...
public void changeEffectiveDate(Integer recordId, Date newDate) {
  LogicManager manager = getBean("logicManager");

  MemberRecord record = manager.findById(recordId);
  record.setEffectiveDate(newDate);
  manager.updateRecord(record);
}
```

Before I added the `evict()` call in the Manager, I noticed that the manager was behaving in unexpected ways. In order to update a record, I'd first have to get that record by calling `findById()`, which would put the record into the Session cache. I'd make changes on that object, then call `updateRecord()` which would call `findById()` to get the (supposedly) persisted data. I realized that this second call to `findById()` would *not* look at the database data, but just pull the object from the cache. This would result in my `oldEffectiveDate` *always* being the same as my newly changed date, since `record` and `oldRecord` would be the exact same object.

To counteract this, I added the call to `evict()`, which I understood to mean that the object would be removed from the cache, forcing Hibernate to go to the database to get the `MemberRecord`. After I made that change, my `MemberRecordDAO` throws an exception when it calls `uniqueResult()`, which says `AssertionFailed: possible nonthreadsafe access to session`. When I run the debugger, I see that both `LogicManager` and `MemberRecordDAO` are using the same `Session`, which is what I thought was correct.

So, my questions:

1. Is my thinking/algorithm correct? Is `evict()` the correct thing to do? Is there a better way? I am not too savvy on Sessions, caching or `evict()`. I want to make sure that this logic is correct before dealing with threading issues.
2. Why is it that accessing the `Session` from the DAO is not threadsafe?

Comment: tl;dr but judging from the title you might wanna look at `session.refresh(...)` and `session.merge(...)`

Comment: @Martin - `refresh()` looks promising. I'm also looking into detaching and reattaching objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution that passed my tests, but it still seems a little gross to me:

**Manager**

```
  public void updateRecord(MemberRecord record) {
    MemberRecord oldRecord = record;
    record = record.clone();   //Added a clone() to MemberRecord
    getSession().evict(record);
    getSession().evict(oldRecord);
    getSession().refresh(oldRecord);
    // At this point, record has all of the new values, but none of the Hibernate
    //  data attached to it, due to the clone(). 
    // oldRecord is populated with the data currently in the database.

    Date oldEffectiveDate = oldRecord.getEffectiveDate();
    if ( isEffective(oldEffectiveDate) && 
         !oldEffectiveDate.equals(record.getEffectiveDate)) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot change date");
    }


    // << Other data checks >>
    memberRecordDAO.update(record);
  }
```

If this type of thing can be done cleaner, please tell me.

Answer (score 2):

The evict() approach will work, but I believe the 'preferred hibernate way of doing things' would be to use Session.merge(), as in:

```
public MemberRecord updateRecord(MemberRecord newRecord) {

    MemberRecord oldRecord = memberRecordDAO.findById(record.getId());

    Date oldEffectiveDate = oldRecord.getEffectiveDate();
    if ( isEffective(oldEffectiveDate) && 
     !oldEffectiveDate.equals(newRecord.getEffectiveDate)) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot change date");
    } else {
       MemberRecord merged = (MemberRecord) session.merge(newRecord);
       return merged;
    }
}
```

Just keep in mind that Session.merge() will update all of the fields of oldRecord with the values from newRecord.

Comment: I don't see how your example sidesteps the problem of `newRecord` being the same as `oldRecord`, which was the whole reason I was using `evict()` in the first place.